# Is there any way in Entity Framework 4 of making Validation produce a warning instead of an error?

Tags: validation, entity-framework-4, warnings

As far as I can see, the validation within Entity Framework is built entirely around the assumption that, if an item fails its validation, it must not be persisted to the database. Is there any mechanism, possibly running parallel to normal validation, of making a constraint on a field produce a warning to the user, rather than an error which prevents the record from being saved/updated?

To be more specific, I have a situation where a particular numerical field has limits on it, but these are advisory rather than hard-and-fast. If the user enters a value outside these limits, they should get a warning, but should still be able to save the record.

In theory, I could subclass the ValidationResult class to make, say, a ValidationWarning class, then create a custom subclass of ValidationResults whose IsValid property was sensitive to the presence of ValidationWarning messages, and ignored them in deciding whether the entity is valid. However, this requirement has arisen in a project which is already someway along in its development, and it would require a lot of refactoring to make this kind of custom subclassing work properly. I would prefer to find a mechanism which could be levered in without creating that much disruption/rework.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement on a project and how I solved it was this. If (ModelState.IsValid) is false, I cleared out the errors out of the ModelState and sent it on its way again,then logged the "error" to another service. This is a bit of a hack and I would'nt recommend doing as it is not exactly best practice.